# I want to call a webservice when the application will uninstall. Is it possible with Android?

Tags: android

*Basically i want to perform some database interaction at the time of uninstall*

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is not possible in Android.

Because there is no methods/API exists to program for the uninstallation time.

Comment: In windows mobile it is possible and i have to implement this in android.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Android.

De-installation of an application is managed by the operating system, and requested by the user in the device settings. The application itself is not started in any way, and there are no hooks in the manifest that you can use to request that some code is run when the user elects to uninstall.

Is your use case as simple as "do this upon de-installation"? Android will wipe any preferences and databases anyway, so once complete the worst case scenario is that you've created files that are left on the phone or SD card.

Alternatively, is your use case something slightly different (for example, trying to restrict the number of devices your software is installed on)? In which case, if you widen the question  to describe what your end goal is, we might be able to help more.